# Python3 пагинация в запросах к API

Tags: python, алгоритм, api, пагинация

Проблема в следующем: есть сайт без API, но я разрыл его фронт и обнаружил AJAX-пагинацию, выглядит она следующим образом: `https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=0&size=40`, я при получении первого(тестового запроса) могу увидеть сколько всего элементов на странице `count`, но при исследованиях я выяснил что `size` не может быть больше 40. А `count` может быть от 1 до нескольких сотен или даже нескольких тысяч. Соответсвенно я хочу создать список url для запросов, при этом у меня есть начальный шаг `from=0`, есть `count` предположим `735`, и есть `max_step=40`. У меня в принципе получилось добиться чего я хочу:

```
{'count': 18, 'start': [0, 40, 80, 120, 160, 200, 240, 280, 320, 360, 400, 440, 480, 520, 560, 600, 640, 680, 720], 'last_step': 15}
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=0&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=40&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=80&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=120&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=160&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=200&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=240&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=280&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=320&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=360&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=400&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=440&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=480&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=520&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=560&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=600&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=640&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=680&size=40
https://example.com/ws/v1.0/list?from=720&size=15
```

Но вид и чистота и читаемость кода меня просто не устраивают жуть:

```
address = 'example.com'
max_step = 40 
count = 735
url = 'https://{address}/ws/v1.0/list?from={start}&size={size}'
    
def calc_requests(count: int, max_step: int) -> dict:
    
    start = [0,]
    count_requests = count // max_step
    if count_requests > 0:
        for i in range(1, count_requests+1):
            start.append(max_step*i)
    requests_dict = {'count': count_requests, 'start': start}
    last_step = count - start[-1] if len(start) > 1 else count - max_step
    if last_step > 0:
        requests_dict['last_step'] = last_step
    if last_step < 0:
        requests_dict['last_step'] = max_step + last_step
    print(requests_dict)
    
    return requests_dict


def get_url_list(calc: dict, url: str, max_step: int):
    size = max_step
    if calc['count'] == 0 and 'last_step' in calc:
        size = calc['last_step']
        request_url = url.format(address=address, start=0, size=size)
        print(request_url)
    elif calc['count'] >= 1:
        for start in calc['start']:
            if start == calc['start'][-1] and 'last_step' in calc:
                size = calc['last_step']
            if start == calc['start'][-1] and 'last_step' not in calc:
                break
            request_url = url.format(address=address, start=start, size=size)
            print(request_url)

test = calc_requests(count, max_step)
print(get_url_list(test, url, max_step))
```

Любые идеи по упрощению, уменьшению, использование `yield` для выдачи ссылки, рекурсия - приветствую все.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
address = 'example.com'
step = 40
count = 735
start = 0

for _ in range(0, count//step):
    print(f'https://{address}/ws/v1.0/list?from={start}&size={step}')
    start += step
if count//step != 0:
    print(f'https://{address}/ws/v1.0/list?from={start}&size={count-start}')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]